# How I call javascript function in Master Page's Content Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is my Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Master.master.cs" Inherits="Master.Master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        function checkMatchPassword() {
            swal("Error!", ".......", "error");
        }

    </script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
```

This is my Content Page's Class (Master Page's Child)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "Password", "checkMatchPassword();", true);
```

I want to call a javascript function in Master Page's content page. But the code I wrote is not working. Please help.

Comment: try to wrap it in $(document).ready();

Comment: call your function with document.ready()

Comment: How will I do? Can you give an example the code?

Comment: Try writing this as your script parameter `$(document).ready(function() {
   checkMatchPassword();
});` <br/>
Make sure you have included jQuery library as this is a jQuery solution. For pure javascript, use `window.onload="checkMatchPassword();"`

Comment: I tried.But not working.Please help

Comment: Above comment is a jQuery solution. For pure javascript solution, use `window.onload="checkMatchPassword();"`

Comment: this code should work. What is "swal" here. Where the swal sunction is defined? Can you just write alert("hi") instead of swal and try if it gets fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work. You must put definition for "swal" function in master page.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to SweetAlert is missing:

Download the SweetAlert (https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert) manuel and add the missing references:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Master.master.cs" Inherits="Master.Master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="scripts/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/sweetalert.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">


        function checkMatchPassword() {
            swal("Error!", ".......", "error");
        }

    </script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
```